# Install completion file via PEAR

Tags: php, pear

I have a PHP command-line tool that I'm trying to distribute via a pear channel.

Installing the binary itself is no problem.

What I'm looking for is a way to install it's associated bash completion file, which should go in `/etc/bash_completion.d/`.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to install files to arbitrary locations with PEAR.

You could write a post-install script which copies an installed file into `/etc/bash_completion.d/`, though.

Comment: Yeah, but it's not run automatically. Users would need to call `pear run-scripts <package>`, which is lame.

Answer (score 1):

I found that you can define custom file roles, which would seem to be the right way to go about this:

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.migrating.customroles.defining.php

Comment: that's better than a post-install script, yes - but people need to install the file role before installing the package, though.

Comment: I assume one can set the file role package as a dependency of the main package. Otherwise, SOL.